# How to use identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

*Description*

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` with `MVC` pattern and I'm trying to create a custom `Roles` for my users.

*Code*

For doing this I setup inside the `ConfigureServices` method this `Identity`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

then inside the `Configure` method I declare this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   new UserRoleSeed(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()).SeedAsync();
}
```

Essentially I used the `Dependency Injection` to pass the `RoleManager` in the `UserRoleSeed` constructor, which is a configuration class for the role:

```
public class UserRoleSeed
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public UserRoleSeed(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async void SeedAsync()
    {
        if ((await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin")) == null)
        {
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
        }
    }
}
```

when I start the application I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' from root provider.'

What I did wrong?

NB: I added only the relevant code.

Comment: https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17333/Custom-user-roles-and-rolebased-authorization-in-ASPNET-core/28352#.W35W3OgzbIU  this might be helps you

Comment: Did you try to create a scope before trying to resolve the `RoleManager` : `app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()` ?

Comment: try to find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805561/asp-net-core-2-identity-di-errors-with-custom-roles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 2 - Identity - DI errors with custom Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805561/asp-net-core-2-identity-di-errors-with-custom-roles)

Comment: @aguafrommars I get the same error if I add `app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()`

Comment: did you resolve the service from the created scope ? `var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope(); var manager = scope.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. resolving `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` from `root provider`
2. `SeedAsync` will cause **object dispose** error.

Try steps below to resolve your issue:

1. Add `IServiceProvider` to `Configure`

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   ```
2. Modify `SeedAsync` from `void` to `Task`

   ```
       public async Task SeedAsync()
   ```
3. Call `SeedAsync` from `Configure`

   ```
   new UserRoleSeed(serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()).SeedAsync().Wait();
   ```

Comment: I make the changes that you have suggested and when I reach this line `_roleManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();` the compiler say: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' from root provider.'`. This happen inside the constructor of `UserRoleSeed`. If instead I use this code: https://pastebin.com/w2se8qT3 the error doesn't appear, but why?

Comment: @Dillinger Do you share the wrong code? My suggestion is adding `IServiceProvider serviceProvider`, you shared me with `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()`.

Comment: Seems working, thanks for your help. Just a question: why my code didn't work and instead the serviceProvider works? I'm learning ASP.NET Core so I'm curios to understand the difference